# making existing url to seo friendly without making change to table

Tags: php, .htaccess

how to make this url to seo friendly urls

```
items.php?itemid=1&title=my title goes here
```

to

```
products/1/my-title-goes-here
```

how it can be done using only .htaccess not making any change to table or code currently data is access through id, don't even changing the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like (not tested)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ http://your web site/items.php?=$1&title=$2 [R=301,L]
```

which matches the patten that starts with products, with the first sub-patten being at least one character long, and anything that is not '/' . Same is true for the second pattern which must end the URL.  You then rewrote that into the actual string your software needs.

Comment: But what about replacing hyphens with spaces in title?

Comment: @anubhava simple use str_replace(' ','-',$title)

Comment: But OP said `how it can be done using only .htaccess not making any change to table or code`

Comment: it did't work for me but little modification made it working RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)(.*)$ item.php?id=$1&title=$2

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Apache module `mod_rewrite` and the respective rewrite rules in the .htaccess file.

[Read this](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) it helped me a lot when I was first starting with it